# How to revert chosen click to play setting?

Tags: firefox

How can I made click-to-play to auto enable plugins for a specific site if I have selected previously: Never activate plugins for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Type `about:permissions` in the address bar and press Enter.
2. Search for the site in question.
3. Click on the dropdown menu next to "Plugins" and choose your new setting.

[image]

---

Alternatively:

1. Right-click on the page and click on "View page info".
2. Click on the "Permissions" tab.
3. Go to the heading entitled "Activate plugins" and change your setting.

[image]